# git status doesn't show the number of non-pushed commits anymore

Tags: git

I have a directory that contain a file: `test.js`. I init the git repository and I make the first commit:

```
myusername@laptop:~/test$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/myusername/test/.git/
myusername@laptop:~/test$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       test.js
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
myusername@laptop:~/test$ git add .
myusername@laptop:~/test$ git commit -m "Test commit"
[master (root-commit) a1ba24e] Test commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.js
```

Then I type: `git status`:

```
myusername@laptop:~/test$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This looks for me like I already pushed my changes. But they are not pushed!

I expected to see this one instead:

```
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I guess that it's because of a new version of `git`.

Is this a new feature or a bug? I would like to see how many commits are not pushed when I type `git status` - but if this is a new feature how can I see the that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based upon your workflow, you did not set a remote when you created your repository.  Therefore, there is no `origin/master` to be ahead of.  Try this and see what happens:

```
git remote add origin <remote_uri>
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
git pull
git status
```